# Presto sql "Value cannot be cast to timestamp"

Tags: sql, presto

I have columns formatted like '2019-01-14' in varchar type and try converting them into timestamp. But keep getting errors:

```
SQL Error [9]: Query failed (#20190114_034630_00658_m4cx9): Value cannot be cast to timestamp: 1960-05-01
```

And have no idea why '1960-05-01' cannot be cast to timestamp while the other columns have the same format can be.

In detail, I'm applying `date_diff` function on them like

```
cast(cast(date_diff('day', cast(l.login_date AS timestamp), cast(u.birthday AS timestamp)) as double) / 365 as integer) as age
```

and seems `birthday` column has the problem.

Comment: Can you run Presto CLI with `--debug` to get full error stacktrace?

Comment: Perhaps there are other characters in that value.  You might want to check that the length is exactly 10.